# Allocating contiguous memory to contain multiple structs with flexible array members

Tags: c, memory, flexible-array-member

Consider a struct containing a flexible array member like the following:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t len;
    char data[];
} Foo;
```

I have an unknown number of Foos, each of which is an unknown size, however I can be certain that all of my Foos together will total exactly 1024 bytes.
How can I allocate 1024 bytes for an array of Foos before knowing the length of each Foo, and then fill in the members of the array later?

Something like this, although it throws a segfault:

```
Foo *array = malloc(1024);
int array_size = 0;

Foo foo1;
strcpy(foo1.data, "bar");
array[0] = foo1;
array_size++;

Foo foo2;
strcpy(foo2.data, "bar");
array[1] = foo2;
array_size++;

for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    puts(array[i].data);
```

The reason for wanting to do this is to keep all the Foos in a contiguous memory region, for CPU cache friendliness.

Comment: Structures with a flexible array as their last member cannot be used as members of other structures or as array elements.

Comment: Suggest changing: `char data[];` to `char *data; Then the variable length data can be elsewhere rather than 'in line'.  This it is easy to declare an array of those structs, similar to:  `Foo myArray[ 1024/sizeof( Foo ) ];`  Note: the struct posted code not contain a 'tag' name and most debuggers use the 'tag' name to be able to access the individual fields within the struct

Comment: @Govind Parmar Is there an alternative approach to creating a memory contiguous array of structs with variable data size?

Comment: An obvious problem with your approach is that there's no guarantee that each subsequent `Foo` would be suitably aligned. Alignment generally requires padding, and if you have an exact amount of storage that's already accounted for, there's no room for padding.

Comment: @user3629249 I'd like to avoid the additional overhead of a dereference from using a pointer if possible

Comment: No dereferencing?  OK, then allocate the MAX amount of room for the `data` array.  This will waste a lot of room when the data array is short, but eliminates the dereference.  The only time I see a dereference being a problem is when trying to 'serialize' the structs for writing to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** have an array of foos, at all, because foo does not have a fixed size, and the defining characteristic of an array is that each object has fixed size and offset from the base computable from its index. For what you want to work, indexing `array[n]` would have to know the full size of `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, ..., `foo[n-1]`, which is impossible, because the language has no knowledge of those sizes; in practice, the flexible array member is just excluded from the size, so `foo[1]` will "overlap" with `foo[0]`'s data.

If you need to be able to access these objects as an array, you need to give up on putting a flexible array member in each one. Instead you could put all the data at the end, and store a pointer or offset to the data in each one. If you don't need to be able to access them as an array, you could instead build a sort of linked list in the allocated memory, storing an offset to the next entry as a member of each entry. (See for example how `struct dirent` works with `getdents` on most Unices.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you cannot have a C array of `Foo`. However, suppose you are willing to store them irregularly and just need to know how much space could be required. This answer shows that.

Let *N* be the number of `Foo` objects there are.

Let *S* be `sizeof(Foo)`, which is the size of a `Foo` object with zero bytes for `data`.

Let *A* be `_Alignof(Foo)`.

Every `Foo` object must be start on an address aligned to *A* bytes. Let this be *A*. The worst case for padding is that the `data` array is one byte, requiring that *A*−1 bytes be skipped before the start of the next `Foo`.

Therefore, in addition the 1024 bytes consumed by the `Foo` objects (including their `data`), we might need (*N*−1)•(*A*−1) bytes for this padding. (The *N*−1 is because no padding bytes are needed after the last `Foo`.)

If each `Foo` has at least one byte of `data`, the most *N* could be is floor(1024/(*S*+1)), because we know that all of the `Foo` objects and their data use at most 1024 bytes.

Therefore 1024 + floor(1024/(*S*+1)−1)*(*A*−1) bytes suffice—1024 bytes for the actual data and floor(1024/(*S*+1)−1)*(*A*−1) for the padding.

Note that the above assumes each `Foo` has at least one byte of `data`. If one or more `Foo` have zero bytes of `data`, *N* could be larger than floor(1024/(*S*+1)). However, after any such `Foo`, no padding is needed, and *N* cannot increase by more than one for each such `Foo` (because reducing the space used by one byte cannot make more for more than one `Foo`). Thus, such a `Foo` could gives us one more `Foo` elsewhere that needs *A*−1 bytes of padding, but it itself does not need padding, so the total amount of padding needed cannot increase.

So, a plan to assign memory for the `Foo` objects is:

- Allocate 1024 + floor(1024/(*S*+1)−1)*(*A*−1) bytes.
- Put the first `Foo` at the start of the allocated memory.
- Put each successive `Foo` at the next *A*-aligned address after the end of the previous `Foo` (including its `data`).

This will not yield an array, of course, just a mass of `Foo` objects within the allocated space. You will need pointers or other means of addressing them.

Per C 2018 7.22.3.4 2:

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose `size` is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

So, chopping up the space returned by `malloc` in an irregular way to use for multiple objects is not a good fit for that specification. I will leave that for others to discuss, but I have not observed a C implementation have a problem with it.